# Output Class Probability distribution for all instances in WEKA

Tags: weka

I am new to WEKA and want to get the probability distribution of all instances over all classes from classify tab to a csv file for further analysis of models.

Please suggest how to go about that in WEKA GUI explorer?

Comment: In Weka 3.8, under test options you can select the button "More options...".  Here you can find the option to output predictions as a csv.  Although this prints to the "Classifier Output" window, it does include the distribution for the predicted class.  You can copy this output to a text editor and, in a two class problem, calculate the probability distribution for the other class.  I am unsure how you can do this for more than two classes.

Comment: @Walter I am searching for the solution that will apply to a dataset having 22 classes. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well this is fairly easy to do with code. Don't know if it is possible via GUI though.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that there is a **more options** button in **test options** under the **classify** tab. There you can choose CSV for **output predictions**. If you click on CSV you can turn **outputDistribution** to true and name your file.Hope this helps.

If this doesn't work then its fairly easy to do this with java code.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you are asking but I gather it is the output from a cross validation/% split run that you want as a csv file? If so, the best place to achieve this is in the Experimenter tab in WEKA. First, click 'New' and add your datasets in the bottom left box after clicking 'add new.' Secondly, add your algorithms in the bottom right box having clicked 'add new.' Finally, change your results destination to 'CSV file' and browse for the file location. You can configure the experiment type and number of repetitions here also. Run the experiment in the next tab and wait for completion. You will find your results in the destination csv.